# Prevent MacBook Pro from going to sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, television

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to set a MacBook Pro to not sleep when you close the lid?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-macbook-pro-to-not-sleep-when-you-close-the-lid)

I would like to prevent my MacBook Pro (2009 version) from going to sleep when I close it. I can do this with a Windows-based laptop, but I could not find an option on the Mac. Is this possible? I want to be able to close it when outputting video to a TV, for example.

Answer (score 3):

If using Lion, it should not go to sleep when an external display is connected. If it does, you can wake it up with an external keyboard.

Comment: Assuming that it is plugged in, it should stay on with an external display connected, while using Lion. If not on Lion, you'll need some sort of Bluetooth device (or possibly a USB keyboard, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 3):

### [InsomniaX 2.0](http://semaja2.net/archives/206)

does a very good job at this.

[image]

Comment: [Doesn't work with Mavericks](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108080/is-insomniax-working-on-mavericks) as of today. As OP didn't specify OS X version, I believe it's worth adding to the answer.