# Is InsomniaX working on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, power-management, macbook-pro

It seems to me that InsomniaX, a utility to let a MacBook stay awake when the lid is closed, is not working on Mavericks. Can anyone confirm for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experience the same. The "Disable **Idle** Sleep" selection is automatically turned off and the computer goes to sleep after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work at my MBA mid 2011, with Mavericks 10.9.3.

Comment: @grgarside Could you detail how exactly it doesn't answer the question? To me, it looks it completely does.

Comment: Apologies, misclicked in the review queue — thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @grgarside Looks like your delete vote is still there.

Comment: Can't remove delete votes on mobile :( It'll disappear after a while though as no one else will vote

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Still didn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It does work to disable the sleep on lid close, however, I've been getting random restarts with it running.

Comment: Which hardware and Mavericks version did it works at for you?