# Run MacBook Pro with lid closed

Tags: sleep-wake

Is there a simple setting to allow a MacBook to continue running with the lid shut?  All signs that I found pointed to no supposedly due to concerns about overheating, but when docked, a MBP is able to be used if the monitor and keyboard are plugged in.

My use case would be running a terminal command that takes awhile, leaving my desk, locking my account, and closing the lid to keep nosy people out.

Answer (score 0):

After looking a little further, I found what I was looking for on this page: [How can I prevent my Macbook Pro 2011 from going to sleep when I close the lid?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45462/how-can-i-prevent-my-macbook-pro-2011-from-going-to-sleep-when-i-close-the-lid)

Answer (score 0):

No. I have run mine with external display, for presentation purposes, but you need something like this.

Why not just lock the display.