# Can I disable Mac sleep mode even when lid is closed?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to set a MacBook Pro to not sleep when you close the lid?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-macbook-pro-to-not-sleep-when-you-close-the-lid)

I have a Macbook Pro (early 2011) with Mountain Lion installed.

Is there a way to prevent my Mac from going to sleep even on lid close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an external monitor plugged in, it will happen automatically.

Otherwise, you can use [InsomniaX](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22211/insomniax).

Comment: cmdline equivalent is: `caffeinate` since `pmset noidle` is deprecated in favor of caffeinate (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)

Comment: Note also that InsomniaX is no more supported on recent version os OSX. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/256335/111817) for alternatives.