# Can I configure a task to run while my MacBook lid is closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, macos, sleep-wake, power-management

Can I use [`pmset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) or a utility like [Power Manager](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) to have a task (such as an arbitrary script or backup) run at a specific time while my Mavericks MacBook Pro's lid is closed? Are there perhaps `pmset` settings I need to change to make such a thing work?

Comment: does [Power Nap](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5394) not do what you want? (you mentioned only backup which it does do)

Comment: @BradAllred: I thought PowerNap only did the Apple things listed, not tasks users can add.

Comment: correct, but you only mentioned backup so I thought i'd mention it.

Comment: @BradAllred: Ah, yes. I mean non-Apple backup software, for example.

Answer (score 1):

While the lid is closed, a `pmset wake` will only wake up your machine very briefly, after which it will go back to sleep again. To keep the machine awake long enough to preform a task, you can [`caffeinate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html) the machine for the amount of time (in seconds) you expect the task to take. For example, to keep the machine awake for 2 minutes, simply add

```
caffeinate -t 120 &
```

early on in the script that runs your task.

Alternatively, `caffeinate` has options for tying the duration of the forced wake period to the completion of the task, but this runs the risk of keeping the machine awake indefinitely, so a safer bet is this expected-time-based approach.