# Use caffeinate to prevent sleep on lid close on battery

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power

The native `caffeinate` utility is not working to prevent my macbook from sleeping when I close the display.  Instead, the system sleeps and various network services ( VPN, screenshares, VOIP calls, messaging clients, file transfers ) to fail while I [walk from my desk to my meeting](http://richd.me/2011/09/laptop-lids/) in < 5 minutes.

Walking around with the laptop lid half open makes it difficult to safely carry with my coffee, and is distinctly uncool.

The native `caffeinate` utility is designed to handle this as a user-friendly replacement for [`pmset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html), but appears to be designed not to work when disconnected from AC power.

Docs via [`man caffeinate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/caffeinate)

> -s Create an assertion to prevent the system from sleeping. This assertion is valid only when system is ***running on AC power***.

Looking for a native alternative to [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/projects/insomniaxinfo/) or [nosleep](https://github.com/integralpro/nosleep).

A timeout feature is essential so that I avoid accidentally stuffing my undead macbook into a bag, resulting in a hot mess.  ( `caffeinate -t`, specifies the timeout value in seconds )

Comment: I fear there is no *native* alternative, as a MacBook is supposed to go to sleep when you close it. :-/

Comment: Walking around with MacBook is _exactly_ why I also want a solution for preventing sleep when lid is closed.

Comment: Did you try the option `-t`, like `caffeinate -t 3600`? According to my experience, it works even if the macbook is running on battery.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, didn't work on initial attempts.  Am I missing something?  Tested 1) `caffeinate -t 3600` 2) Close laptop 3) Wait 5s 4) Open laptop to find login screen and disconnected network services.

Comment: @here I didn't try to close the lid, though. I just ran the command with `-t` option when my macbook is on battery, and it didn't go to sleep. I haven't tried with the lid closed, but it looks the macbook will be forced to sleep as soon as you close the lid. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I was thinking you were looking for a way to make it work when it runs on battery only, without the lid closed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's not ideal, but here's a solution. To prevent the laptop from sleeping when the lid is closed and you're running on battery, run the following commands:

```bash
sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1
```

To re-enable laptop sleeping when the lid is closed and you're running on battery, run the following commands:

```bash
sudo pmset -b sleep 5; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 0
```

The "5" in the second set of commands represents the number of minutes before sleeping when on battery; adjust as desired for your laptop.

This is a bit dangerous, since if you forget to re-enable your settings, the laptop will never sleep when on battery. Because of this, I've written a shell script to automatically re-enable the settings:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#***************************************************************************
#*** noz - prevent laptop from sleeping when lid is closed
#***************************************************************************

#***** set some defaults *****
BATTERY_SLEEP=5 # in minutes
DEF_WAKE_LEN=300 # in seconds

#***** determine timeout value *****
timeout_len=${1:-$DEF_WAKE_LEN}

function prevent_sleep() {
    echo
    echo -n "Preventing sleep for $timeout_len seconds; press <enter> to continue..."

    sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1
    sudo pmset -b sleep 0
}

function enable_sleep() {
    # $1: <enter> = 0, timeout = 1, Ctrl-C = undef

    #----- insert a newline for timeout or Ctrl-C -----
    if [[ ${1:-1} -eq 1 ]]; then    echo; fi
    echo "Restoring previous battery sleep setting: $BATTERY_SLEEP"

    sudo pmset -b disablesleep 0
    sudo pmset -b sleep $BATTERY_SLEEP

    #----- sleep on timeout only -----
    if [[ ${1:--1} -eq 1 ]]; then   sudo pmset sleepnow; fi
    exit
}

#***** prevent it from sleeping *****
prevent_sleep

#***** trap Ctrl-C *****
trap enable_sleep INT

#***** wait for an enter *****
read -t $timeout_len
rc=$?

#***** re-enable normal sleep *****
enable_sleep $rc
```

The shell script will disable sleeping until you hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, at which point it will re-enable the sleep settings (alternately, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and achieve the same thing). It will also set a timeout (defaults to 300 seconds/5 minutes) after which the sleep settings will automatically be re-enabled, and the laptop will be forced to go to sleep. While this would be a pain if you're using your laptop in a meeting, it will be a lifesaver if you forgot and put your laptop in your bag to go home.

Astute readers will note that these commands require `sudo`; sadly, that's unavoidable AFAIK. What I've done on my system is to make it so that I don't have to enter my password to run `pmset` as root. To do that, edit the `sudoers` file (`sudo visudo`) and add this line:

```bash
joe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pmset
```

replacing "joe" with your username. You could probably achieve the same result (i.e. running the script without having to enter your password) by running the shell script SETUID, but I don't like doing that; opening up this one command via sudoers seems less risky to me.

To run the script, stick it in a directory on your `PATH` and invoke it as such:

```bash
noz [<timeout in seconds>]
```

When you get to where you're going, simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and you're good to go. And if you forget about it, it will automatically reset and sleep.

There's probably a way to achieve all of this via AppleScript, so that you can then assign it a hot key and what not; I'll try that if I ever get tired of running this from the command line.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! A suggestion / simplification: I don't think you need to change the `sleep` setting. Just switch `disablesleep` on and off. `pmset -a disablesleep 1` and `pmset -a disablesleep 0` work fine for me. My MacBook doesn't got to sleep when I close the lid. All other settings remain the same.

Comment: Github user iccir has made a free app called Fermata that uses this trick under the hood and wraps it up nicely with a menubar icon and a timer, etc. I just tried it on Mojave (10.14.2) and it worked great for me. https://github.com/iccir/Fermata

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that `sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1` will persist the state across reboots, and that the **Sleep** option under the Apple logo menu () will stay disabled until you re-enable sleep. You _must_ run `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0` to re-enable sleep.

Answer (score 10):

There's no native way to do it. Here is what I got after some searching and trials:

[image]

Note:

- Nosleep's kernel extension failed to be loaded on High Sierra
- The private SPI is NOT supported by Apple after High Sierra. [Fermata](https://github.com/iccir/Fermata) switched to the `pmset` method after version 1.1
- You may need to disable Gatekeeper to let [Insomnia](https://github.com/semaja2/InsomniaX) work as expected.
- The other apps I tried don't work with lid closed

Comment: There's one hacky native way I know how to do this: Start a screen sharing session with the target Mac and it won't sleep even if the lid is closed and battery power is removed.  I'm referring to the built-in macOS screen sharing functionality and not a 3rd party's.  When a session is active the`screensharingd` process on the target mac takes out a the power assertion`PreventSystemSleep` and this is actually respected, preventing system sleep.

Answer (score 8):

Github user iccir has made a very handy little free menubar app called Fermata that does exactly what you want: keeps a MacBook awake with the lid closed, and allows you to set a timeout duration.

I just tried it on Mojave (10.14.2) and it worked great for me. https://github.com/iccir/Fermata

Answer (score 8):

tested on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.6

works both on battery mode and charger mode.

```
sudo pmset disablesleep 1
```

do not forget to restore settings by

```
sudo pmset disablesleep 0
```

My daughter often close the lid once she found I left my seat while I am still listening YouTube, this pmset command helps me to continue listening YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this app](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/)? I find it very useful for exactly what you're after.

I'm fairly sure it has a timeout feature that you set within the settings of the app.

Comment: Thanks @mitchell-d .  The question is specifically asking for a native solution, such as caffeinate.  There are other apps suggested in [is-there-any-way-to-set-a-macbook-pro-to-not-sleep-when-you-close-the-lid](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-macbook-pro-to-not-sleep-when-you-close-the-lid?rq=1)  Nonetheless, I tried the [caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) app you recommend it does *not* prevent my macbook from sleeping when I close the lid.